# Web Scraping Google-Sheets ImportXML - xpath - specific Number in URL

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a specific Number from an URL, which is hyperlinked on the website.

Please see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6tDLK1KPmF-syTxhH8XhFgm1AquQ0LClQiK-unEZxE/edit#gid=1076703221) a copy of my spreadsheet.

In Row "I" - i did a code, so it will directly go the the search of the eBay website, and combines the EAN number `="https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw="&""&D2`

this is the outcome:
https://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=8713439712292

Till here it works.

On the page, i want the ebay Kategorie ID for that articel, which can be found as a Hyperlink on the Categories [See Image of eBay Categorie here] Navigation on the left.
In the URl it is always the first Number, eg. https://www.ebay.de/sch/**158817**/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=650135421227
[InspectCode URL I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fP79.png)

All I want know, is to put the Number 158817 in my google spreadsheet.

With this code

```
=IMPORTXML(I2;"//*[@id='x-refine__group__0']/ul/li/ul/li/ul")
```

I only get the categorie name, but I need the number to make my CSV upload work.

What code do I need? Can Someone please guide me?
thank you
Lisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With A1 = `https://www.ebay.de/sch/**158817**/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=650135421227`, try this

```
=regexextract(IMPORTXML(A1;"//*[@id='x-refine__group__0']/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/a/@href");"[0-9]+")
```

assuming that the url is always at the same position in the nomenclature

or, to get all numbers

```
=arrayformula(regexextract(IMPORTXML(A1;"//*[@id='x-refine__group__0']/ul/li//a/@href");"[0-9]+"))
```